# Ubunutu Mate installed on pendrive doesn't boot, even though it was installed with "something else" option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mate, usb-installation

I wanted a portable device with my programs and and data, so I installed Ubuntu Mate on my pendrive.
I follwed this instruction: https://www.fosslinux.com/10212/how-to-install-a-complete-ubuntu-on-a-usb-flash-drive.htm
The process of installation didnt go flawless, it did show an error:

`installed linux-image-5.3.0.51-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1`.

But after closing error window, it showed message of correct installation. When i tried to boot it up it jumped to windows which is installed on my computer's HDD. When i browsed files from pendrive i could clearly see there was folder boot.
So the question is, where did i go wrong or how can i fix it.

EDIT: typo

Comment: If your computer is booting UEFI, you need an efi boot partition. For a system that boots both BIOS and UEFI see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Comment: I tried your tutorial but unfortunetely I got very much lost with copying files and as I found some partition names not comsistent with their '/dev/sdx3' etc. and copying boot.

Comment: sdx corresponds to sdd in the pictures. Copy the boot and the EFI folders from the Ubuntu ISO file. I fixed some other typos.

Comment: A thing that I would like to ask is What are some common problems with instalaton on usb keys? Because I am trying for couple of days now instaling distros and there are allways problems, i tried doing simple basic instalation using VBox and physical computer and it never boots up. There is allways some error.

Comment: In the instalation process without using "something else", there isn't much place to mess up. So what can go wrong every single time? Could the usb be broken even though i used it before and it was fine?

Comment: First check the ISO's MD5SUM then check out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot

Comment: Thanks a lot of theory to understand this is just what I need, I realy hate working with "black box'es".